# Iterating over nodes and its childs and modify data

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I'm using Virtual Tree List for delphi 2009. I've created a tree with data such as:

```
type
  PTreeData = ^TTreeData;
  TTreeData = record
    FCaption: String;
    FPath: String;
  end;
```

I want to iterate over all elements but in specific order. I need to acquire first top level node, and then iterate over all of its children and modify `FPath` field. When I'm done with its children I want to get another top level node, and so on.

First of all I don't know how to itterate over top level nodes.

Thanks in advance for any tips on this

Comment: Not appropriate for this particular question, but see also the `IterateSubtree` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how to iterate top level nodes. Please note (as Smasher left in his comment) that nodes are being initialized if needed by using `GetFirst` and `GetNextSibling` what might slow down the iteration a little bit. However you can use the `GetFirstNoInit` and `GetNextNoInit` functions (if you have nodes already initialized) and you might get better performance.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Data: PTreeData;
  Node: PVirtualNode;
begin
  Node := VirtualStringTree1.GetFirst;
  while Assigned(Node) do
  begin
    Data := VirtualStringTree1.GetNodeData(Node);
    // here you can access your data
    Node := VirtualStringTree1.GetNextSibling(Node);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It almost works :) Instead GetNext I need to use GetNextSibling to iterate over top level nodes only. Plz correct this so I could accept your answer. And thanks! :)

Comment: But Jacek, your question explicitly says you need to iterate over all the top-level nodes *and their children*.